# "We canceled your request to Enroll in Lightning Login because you denied the request using Salesforce Authenticator."

Tags: authentication, mfa, multi-factor-authentication

I'm getting the same error multiple times. The request isn't even shown on my phone- it denies automatically. What should I do now?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you have [Multi-factor Authentication for User Interface Logins](https://advancedcommunities.com/blog/multi-factor-authentication-in-salesforce/) enabled in the settings for your user account and see if the error persits?

Comment: Could someone else have your enrolment on their device and be doing the denial?

Comment: Since about a month I am getting this exact error for one particular sandbox. Not for production, not for other sandboxes, just this one. And not just me, the administrator, but other users as well. I thought it was related to the Winter'24 rollout, but I see that other people are experiencing this much longer ago.